# Apache Camel K integration build failed without error details

Tags: apache-camel-k

Running the following Apache Camel K route works as expected:

```yaml
- from:
    uri: "timer:tick"
    parameters:
      period: "1000"
    steps:
      - to: "log:info"
```

But the same route using Kamelets does not work:

```yaml
- from:
    uri: "kamelet:timer-source"
    parameters:
      period: "1000"
    steps:
      - to: "kamelet:log-sink"
```

When running with `--dev` I get the following output:

```
$ kamel run kamelets.yaml --dev
Integration "kamelets" created
Progress: integration "kamelets" in phase Initialization
Progress: integration "kamelets" in phase Building Kit
Condition "IntegrationPlatformAvailable" is "True" for Integration kamelets: default/camel-k
Integration "kamelets" in phase "Initialization"
Condition "KameletsAvailable" is "True" for Integration kamelets: kamelets [log-sink,timer-source] found in repositories: (Kubernetes[namespace=default], Empty[])
Integration "kamelets" in phase "Building Kit"
Condition "IntegrationKitAvailable" is "False" for Integration kamelets: creating a new integration kit
Integration Kit "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Build Submitted"
Build "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Scheduling"
Build "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Pending"
Build "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Running"
Integration Kit "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Build Running"
Build "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Failed"
Build "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Initialization" (recovery 1 of 5)
Build "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Scheduling" (recovery 1 of 5)
Build "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Pending" (recovery 1 of 5)
Build "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Running" (recovery 1 of 5)
Build "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Failed" (recovery 1 of 5)

...

Integration Kit "kit-cfbqpvmt9prs73fm0t00", created by Integration "kamelets", changed phase to "Error"
Progress: integration "kamelets" in phase Error
Error: integration "kamelets" deployment failed
```

What am I missing? Is there any way to see why the build has failed?

Comment: My best guess is that it failed either the build or the publishing phase to the container registry. For anyone having similar problems, if this is something happening, you can get some build information having a look at Build and IntegrationKit custom resources, ie `kubectl get build xyz -o yaml` and `kubectl get ik xyz -o yaml`.